# Visual Studio reports that property has no getter, even though intellisense says it does

Tags: c#, ldap

I am using the LDAP connection class, working from [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection.aspx).

I have instantiated the class using the string constructor like so:

```
LdapConnection ld = new LdapConnection("LDAP://8.8.8.8:8888");
```

I now want to set my credentials so I am trying to do the following:

```
ld.Credential.UserName = "Foo";
```

But I get the following error:

> The property or indexer 'System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryConnection.Credential' cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor.

However, when typing this, intellisense shows the following:

[image]

This description suggests that UserName should indeed have a Get Accessor, what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [LdapConnection.Credential Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection.credential.aspx) doesn't have a `get` accessor, so you can't retrieve its current value and set the `UserName` property on the returned NetworkCredential instance. You can only assign to the LdapConnection.Credential Property:

```
ld.Credential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
```

or

```
var credential = new NetworkCredential();
credential.UserName = userName;
credential.Password = password;
ld.Credential = credential;
```

or

```
ld.Credential = new NetworkCredential
{
    UserName = userName,
    Password = password,
};
```

Comment: I think the question is also aimed at why intellisense thinks there's a getter. Could you explain that?

Comment: The screenshot shows the documentation for the NetworkCredential.UserName property, not the LdapConnection.Credential property. The NetworkCredential.UserName property does have both `get` and `set` accessors.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: Even if the description were incorrect, it isn’t IntelliSense’s fault, but the documentation of the .NET library. IntelliSense merely displays the summary associated with the member.

Comment: Properties with a setter only (i.e. `CanWrite` but not `CanRead`) are rare. Another example (from a more frequently used assembly) comes from typing `var doc = new XmlDocument(); doc.XmlResolver. `. Intellisense *could* be a bit more helpful by *not* listing any members of the `XmlResolver` class after we type the last period. The last period is wrong in all cases for a set-only property. After typing `doc.XmlResolver` the only valid continuation is `=`, that is assignment.